# Converting int to char

Tags: c

Task is to get `int` using `scanf("%d")` then print it again using `printf("%с")` without standard functions like atoi , itoa .As i understood i need to divide all numbers then add `\0` char and print it, however how can i divide it. I thought about loop for dividing  `number%10 + /0` and `number/10` to decrease number for 1 character .
Therefore code should look smoothing like this

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

main(void)
{
int number,reserve ;
char Array[50];
scanf_s("%d",&number);
if (number > 0 || number == 0)
{
    do
    {
        reserve = number % 10;
        printf("%c", reserve + '/0');
        number /= 10;
    } while (number != 0);
}
else
{
    number *= -1;
    printf("-");
    do
    {
        reserve = number % 10;
        printf("%c", reserve + '/0');
        number /= 10;
    } while (number != 0);

}
_getch();
return 0;
```

}

As well there can be negative number so i need some `if` statement to check if it is negative and in case it is loop should avoid it it so we won't get   smthing like `-%10`

So i don't know if loop is correct (hope someone will fix it and explain me how it is supposed to be). Waiting for your advices.

Comment: The loop control is wrong: for example for `42` you will need `2` loops not `42`. Try `do { ... } while (number != 0);`. And think carefully about the loop content. Please *run* your code!

Comment: You should look into [proper C formatting](//prohackr112.tk/r/proper-c-formatting). Or learn how to [thoroughly obfuscate your code](//prohackr112.tk/r/proper-c-obfuscation).

Comment: `itoa` is not a standard function

Answer (score 1):

One side effect of the line

```
number = number % 10;
```

is that you lose the original value of `number`.  So when you go to do

```
number = number/10;
```

it would always get the value zero.  To fix this, store the original value somewhere else, or use another variable to do your character conversion (modulo 10, then plus `\0`).

Also, your loop needs to be re-examined.  This process of modulo, add `\0`, divide, repeat, should stop when the result of the division is zero (i.e. there are no more digits to print).  Another thing to think about is: in what order are these digits being printed?

I'll leave it to you to to figure out how to determine if the value of an `int` is greater than or less than zero, since you didn't attempt that in this snippet.

Comment: Well i fixed mistake when i was getting 0 (appreciate for hint) but now the problem is reversed number.

Comment: To reverse the order, you can build the converted string in a buffer (array of `char`). Either build it backwards (high index to low index) and print it forwards (such as with `printf()` or build it forwards and then somehow print it backwards. (Watch out for the padding, though.) There is educational value in letting you figure these kinds of things out, but I'll give you the idea and let you figure out the code.

Comment: Look i edited question . Now code can handle negative numbers .I know how to make reverse but  im stuck on saving characters to array correctly  (wont all numbers add to each others ) it would be grate if u could help me with this .

Comment: I am pleased that you are making progress, but significantly changing the question like that is generally frowned upon on StackOverflow because it makes the answers inconsistent with the question. If you have another question, please just ask another question. That said, you don't seem to be using your `Array` as a buffer to store the converted string (or using `Array` at all for that matter). The idea is to convert the whole number into a string, then print the converted string. (Because you don't know how long the converted string will be until after you've converted it.)

Answer (score 0):

this will help you, adopt for your purposes

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int a;
    int i = 0;
    int str_size = 0;   
    char str[11] = {};
    char tmp;

    scanf("%d", &a);

    while (a) {
        str[str_size++] = a % 10 + '0';
        a /= 10;
    }

    str_size--;

    while (i < str_size) { // rewind 
        tmp = str[i];
        str[i++] = str[str_size];
        str[str_size--] = tmp;
    }
    printf("%s", str);

    return 0;
}
```